# Is there a resource that documents all mobile device screen resolutions in one location?

Tags: mobile, pixel

I could not find a complete guide of this nor did I know who to contact about possibly making a wiki here for it (if it exists or not allowed please remove).  I cannot nor want to remember everything in regards to pixel dimensions when designing for mobile devices but I'd like to have a list of the pixel dimensions for:

```
Device                                  Width   Height

Apple iPad
Apple iPhone 3
Apple iPhone 4
Apple iPhone 5
Apple Mini
Google Nexus 7 
Asus Transformer Pad Infinity TF700
Google Nexus 10
Asus Transformer Pad TF300
Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1
```

If someone knows a complete guide for all major tablet and mobile devices that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the iOS specifications in one single page, it's hard to find all resolutions in one single place, because the list is growing up everyday, and some of them becomes obsoletes soon, but fortunately that information is not hard to accomplish, as soon as you need to now one, is just a Google search far from you, and you could create your own list with some time.

This is the iOS cheat sheet of resolutions, I hope it helps.
http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/the-ios-design-cheat-sheet-volume-2/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of the most common devices http://mydevice.io/devices/. This of course is not a complete list but is compiled for the most common devices.

I would also check out the mixin on Codepen for front end developers: [Display the breakpoint using Sass Display the breakpoint using Sass](http://codepen.io/stacy/pen/JoQRyN). Check out her profile for other responsive design helping code.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 3, iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 screen resolutions [here](http://www.iphoneresolution.com/)

Answer (score 0):

**Mobile Device Reference**

Can you use these?

There's no good way to know if such info is more up-to-date than that from another source

- [Mobile device screen resolutions](http://www.annielytics.com/list-of-mobile-device-screen-resolutions/)
- [Mobile device pixel density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density)
- [Cellphone screen resolution](http://cartoonized.net/cellphone-screen-resolution.php)