# What is the retina and non-retina resolution of iPhone5 in pixels?

Tags: resolution, ppi, ios

What is the non-retina/retina resolution of iPhone5 in pixels. (Double or half of `640px x 1136px` screen size)?

Is the retina `640px x 1136px` or is that the non-retina?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with graphic design, it is about hardware resolution. Additionally, it shows a complete lack of effort.

Comment: This question, if worded better, and in regards to design could be a valuable question.  @user22966 you might find this helpful from a Google Search: [Designing for Retina display](http://bjango.com/articles/designingforretina/).

Comment: I don't think this is unrelated to GD, we actually have a few similar questions. This one for example lists most of the resolutions for devices: [**Is there a resource that documents all mobile device screen resolutions in one location?**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16158/is-there-a-resource-that-documents-all-mobile-device-screen-resolutions-in-one-l), and the direct link to the resolutions list: http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/the-ios-design-cheat-sheet-volume-2/

Answer (score 0):

1136px x 640px is the resolution of the iphone 5 retina screen.

So for example the default start up image for apps is called Default-568h@2x.png and is at 1136px x 640px

So I guess if you wanted a lower resolution it would be half that 568px x 320px but I would not recommend this.

Comment: Sorry if this didn't sound graphic design related, but I didn't want to make my question sound so wordy. I've seen so many templates for setting up mobile devices, but the normal "retna" resoluions for Android/iOS don't seem to make my images crisp aka don't seem retna.